# How to show crossbar property page of a directshow hardware device?

Tags: c#, directshow, aforge

My question in summary: Is there a way to show a running video capture device's crossbar property page while not being the graph creator but knowing the moniker string. Can it be done? I am also think that it can be also done if I have the result of graph object Do you agree?

In detail: I am currently using aforge directshow library to capture images. Unfortunately video capture device class has a method only to call the property page of the device. I dont want to change the source code and there is no way available for me too override the capture function as it is hidden. So Is this possible when the IGraphBuilders result is hidden from outside that I can find the crossbar (IAMCrossbar filter interface in the graph builders created graph.). I can see the moniker string but not know how to recover created IAMCrossbar implementer.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were a creator of the graph, you would need to explicitly add crossbar filter into the graph before you could access its property pages. If the library does not do this and crossbar filter is not present in the graph, I don't think you can access it. You need to take over graph creation to make sure crossbar is there.

Comment: I am sure that the underlying code of the aforge library creates the filter graph correctly with crossbar because I modified their soruce before to get this crossbar page. Unfortunatly it is encapsulated in somewhere I can not override or inherit. Is it possible for me to recover filter graph while not being the one who created or is it possible for me to get the crossbar object even If I am not the creator.

Comment: If you could modify the code, you would definitely access the crossbar. Otherwise, crossbar is not require for the capture graph to run so it is possible that there is no crossbar filter in the application which captures video well.